# C# WindowsForms looks different in runtime

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a text box and a search button which, in design time look perfectly as I want them. But once I run the program the button apparently changes location without explanation:

Design time
[image]

Run Time
[image]

Note: The container form "AutoScaleMode" is currently set as "None". It was set as "Font" and it looked like this in run time:
[image]

Which was worst. I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 in Windows 10.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: This is a DPI issue.  WinForms doesn't scale well to a DPI that isn't 100%.  Check your monitor settings, it is probably set to 120%.  In Windows 10, this is labled "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" in Display Settings.

Comment: What is the TextBox’s Autosize property set to ? It looks like it is adjusting its height.

Comment: @JoshPart I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. I'm updating my question to include this.

Comment: @Pulle, it didn't work :/

Comment: @BradleyUffner actually, it is set to 125% xD, so, if that's the problem, is there a way to fix it independently of windows configuration? (I don't know display settings on the machine that will be running my program, nor do I want to depend on that).

Comment: @MarkHall TextBox doesn't have an Autosize property or I'm not being able to find it, both by right click -> properties in design view or by code... it's missing.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx.  Looks like it isn’t a browsable property.

Comment: I have VS 2012 and Win 8, the same issue.

Comment: Maybe set `Multiline` property of the `TextBox` to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the workaround I found was to actually design based on run time appearance:

Design Time
[image]

Run Time
[image]

Which at human sight, seems pretty well (?).
In this case I set 15pt font for the textbox and 32 height for the buttons.